# How to Display Webview in fixed width and height

Tags: java, android, layout, webview

Sorry, I've been searching this forum and got no exact answer. so I ask my own.

I have a class that display two layouts , glView and webview , with target portrait screen 640x960 . i plan to split the layout.  so it would look that my background drawn  at (0,0,640,480) or half of the portrait screen. , and i want my webview drawn at (0,481,640,479) which is occupy the other half from the middle to the bottom.  however, i failed and couldn't figure out how to achieve the layout i want.  How to set the webView size & Position ?

PS: if i set the layout to align bottom then the webview is indeed in the middle to bottom position however i need to specify the exact position.. and the worst.. when it loads the url , it will use the whole screen, covering all my first layout and i am lost.  so how to make the webview display the loaded url into the webview specified width and height.

Thank you.. sorry for my bad english.

anyway, this is my code (i created all programatically, i didn't use any xml layout)

```
    glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glView.setRenderer(this);
    glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(glView);
    webView = new WebView(this);    
    this.showWV(false); //handler message , i hide it in certain screen.

    //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
       new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(webView, params);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use an xml layout?

Comment: it doesn't matter even i use layout, i was just modifying sample game code from mario zachner beginning android games ebook , using his framework (he don't use any layout). what i am trying to accomplish here is to set the webview in the position and set its width & height manually, also load the url in that exact size, not to enlarge itself and occupy the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` to split screen. Just set height = 0 and weight = 1 of `GLSurfaceView` and `WebView` both. In your case the code will be:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this); // Use LinearLayout instead of Relative

glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
glView.setRenderer(this);
glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);

// height is 0, weight is 1
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1);
layout.addView(glView, params);

webView = new WebView(this);
this.showWV(false); //handler message , i hide it in certain screen.
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

// height is 0, weight is 1
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1);
layout.addView(webView, params);

webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

setContentView(layout);
```

Or you can use `RelativeLayout` with hardcoded height and width values:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this); // Use LinearLayout instead of Relative

glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
glView.setRenderer(this);
glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);
glView.setId(123); // set id

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(640, 480);
layout.addView(glView, params);

webView = new WebView(this);
this.showWV(false); //handler message , i hide it in certain screen.
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(640, 480);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, glView.getId()); // set WebView position is below GLSurfaceView
layout.addView(webView, params);

webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

setContentView(layout);
```

**UPD:**
Without hardcoded values, using invisible view:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this); // Use LinearLayout instead of Relative

// create a fake view with zero size and place it to center of RelativeLayout
View fakeView = new View(this); 
fakeView.setId(24736); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
layout.addView(fakeView, params);

glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
glView.setRenderer(this);
glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);
glView.setId(123); // set id

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, fakeView.getId()); // set position is above fakeView
layout.addView(glView, params);

webView = new WebView(this);
this.showWV(false); //handler message , i hide it in certain screen.
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, fakeView.getId()); // set WebView position is below fakeView
layout.addView(webView, params);

webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: thank you, i am stick with relative layout i think, i almost get it right with the code you provided, the only problem is the hard coded value, is there any way to change it to percentage to fit in different resolution.

Comment: It is possible if use fake invisible view in the center of `RelativeLayout`. See my updated answer.

Comment: i'm on the right track, everything's worked except that i am now thinking about maintain the original purpose on show or hide the webview.  as you can see my `this.showWV(false);` this is the handler to call UI Thread that i don't want the webview(and its layout) to appear , the code set the webview invisibility. 
before using your code, it's worked, i mean i can control the webview visibility. but now, it's not worked. the webview (or the blank layout) is appearing from the start which i dont want.. i mean to only display it on certain screen when i set the handler msg to true.

Comment: Thank You erakitin !, i play around with the layout and i could finally understand little enough to make it worked as i want.. I solved it by providing `layout.removeView(fakeView); and layout.removeView(webView);` this way, the layout won't appear anymore. the transition between screen or view is not good though, it came out sometimes all black, and the glview seems like blink, gone, come out the webview first and followed by GLView.. but that's another problem i think. i am glad how i could control the webview. Thanks again!. wish u a joyful day.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` class:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(640, 480);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
webView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

then add the webview to the layout. You can locate the other view at the bottom of the screen with a new LayoutParams instance and `addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);`

Comment: thank you, i am trying it along with the answer from erakitin.

Comment: @ganero note that my awnser will set the view to a fixed size, so on screens that are smaller or bigger than 640x960, the views migth not be positioned/ sized right

Comment: that's right, i tried it. that's why i need another method. thanks