# Set webview dimensions programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a webview in my code, and I'm trying to set the dimensions via programmatically. Is there a way i can do it?

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: yeah, we need to see what have you tried and if you can post an image of what you want?

Comment: Best one U can use .. [Relative or Linear layout for webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550628/how-to-display-webview-in-fixed-width-and-height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use RelativeLayout instead

EXAMPLE:

Suppose you want a WebView of size (50, 60) on your screen at position (70, 80)

```
// RelativeLayout. though you can use xml RelativeLayout here too by `findViewById()`

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
// webView
WebView w= new WebView(this);
    w.setId(0X100);
    w.setScrollContainer(false);
// Setting layout params to our RelativeLayout
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 60);

// Setting position of our ImageView
layoutParams.leftMargin = 70;
layoutParams.topMargin = 80;

// Finally Adding the imageView to RelativeLayout and its position
relativeLayout.addView(w, layoutParams);
```